# Swift error: Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1a1264378) to 'NSNumber' (0x1a126f900)

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error in Xcode (swift):

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x1a1264378) to 'NSNumber' (0x1a126f900).

I made it clear where the error is with //ERROR: ("...")

Code:

```
import UIKit
import iAd
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox

let MAX : UInt32 = 4
let MIN : UInt32 = 1

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {


  var chances = 10
  var won = 0
  var highscore = 0
  var random = Int(arc4random_uniform(MAX) + MIN)
  var sound = 1022 //sound if you won
  var sound2 = 1105 //sound if reset
  var sound3 = 1321 //sound if lose
  var welkmute = 1 //mute = 1 and unmute = 2

  @IBOutlet weak var timeswon: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var Banner: ADBannerView!
  @IBOutlet weak var Highscores: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var mute: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var unmute: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var chancesleft: UILabel!




  func unmUte() {
    unmute.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState())
    mute.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState())

  }

  func mUte() {
    mute.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState())
    unmute.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState())
  }


  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  @IBAction func Mute(sender: AnyObject) {
    sound = 4095
    sound2 = 4095
    sound3 = 4095
    mUte()

    defaults.setObject("1", forKey: "GetMute")
    defaults.synchronize()

  }

  @IBAction func Unmute(sender: AnyObject) {
    sound = 1022
    sound2 = 1105
    sound3 = 1321
    unmUte()

    defaults.setObject("2", forKey: "GetMute")
    defaults.synchronize()

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //unmUte()

    Banner.hidden = true
    Banner.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true


    if defaults.valueForKey("GetHighScore") != nil {
        highscore = defaults.valueForKey("GetHighScore") as! NSInteger
    }

    Highscores.text = "Highscore: \(highscore)"



    if defaults.valueForKey("GetMute") != nil {
        welkmute = defaults.valueForKey("GetMute") as! NSInteger   //ERROR: (Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1)

        if welkmute == 1 {
            mUte()
        }

        if welkmute == 2 {
            unmUte()

        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving a `String` to `NSUserDefaults` and then you are reading a `NSNumber`. That's not possible and that's what the error message says.

`NSUserDefaults` has dedicated methods to handle integers

Set:

- Swift 1 and 2:

  ```
  defaults.setInteger(2, forKey: "GetMute")
  ```
- Swift 3:

  ```
  defaults.set(2, forKey: "GetMute")
  ```

  `defaults.synchronize()` is generally not needed.

Get:

- Swift 1 and 2:

  ```
  welkmute = defaults.integerForKey("GetMute")
  ```
- Swift 3:

  ```
  welkmute = defaults.integer(forKey:"GetMute")
  ```

Two notes:

- Never use `valueForKey` in `NSUserDefaults` for objects. It's `objectForKey`.
- Whenever possible use Swift native types (`Int` rather than `NSInteger`).

Comment: But note that `defaults.setInteger` will go away in Swift 3 (it will be inferred, but you can't call it explicitly).